# How many bytes can a GameBoy copy from Work RAM into VRAM in one vblank?

Tags: video, game-boy

How many bytes of data can be copied from work RAM into VRAM during the "safe time" while the PPU is not refreshing the LCD?

I'm asking about the simplest possible case, when I am copying from e.g. `D000` to `8000` onwards, without any computation.

**Edited to add**: I have tried out a couple of emulators, and it seems MAME is emulating enough details of the PPA's behaviour that it seems to produce glitchy video output when the copy takes too long. That makes me hopeful that I can use that for experimental measurements.

Comment: By using DuckDuckGo with "gameboy How many bytes can I copy from Work RAM into VRAM in one vblank?", I got https://gbdev.gg8.se/forums/viewtopic.php?id=495, https://imanoleasgames.blogspot.com/2017/04/last-crown-warriors-1-building-scroll.html, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307702. I think this would be a good start.

Comment: @Olivier That SO link is not relevant, but the other two seem interesting. But neither actually contains a hard upper bound number.

Comment: What method of copy do you think of? The throughput depends heavily on this.

Comment: @thebusybee well like I said, it would be a straight copy, so whatever is fastest. In fact, since I only need 1-bit graphics, I should be able to copy just every second byte. So something like `ld a, (hl+); ld [de] a; inc e; inc e` in an unrolled loop should get me 24 T-states per byte (plus some overhead for the occasional `inc d` when `e` overflows).

Comment: I know the Sharp LR35902 isn't really a Z80, but on the Z80 the fastest way to clear memory was to move the stack pointer to the end of the block and push all of the registers onto the stack in a loop or maybe unrolled loop, can't remember for sure. I think a similar method was used for fast memory copies but I'm also not 100% sure. So I'm even less sure this trick works to any degree on the LR35902.

Comment: @hippietrail given that I can make do with just writing every second byte of the tileset, I think it's faster to skip every second byte than pushing both.